# OrderBy in Angular.js for (key,value) object in reverse based on keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display the following results in the reverse order using javascript / Angular.js. This is an associative array with keys as Year(Numerical) and value as array of objects of months of those year.

```
 var obj =  { '1991': [{'year':1991,'month':'Jan'},{'year':1991,'month':'Feb'}],
      '1992': [{'year':1992,'month':'March'},{'year':1992,'month':'Dec'}],
      '2000': [{'year':2000,'month':'Jan'}]
    }
```

SO when this basically shows data on html using `ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj"` it shows 1991 as first and 2000 as last. I just want to reverse my order of display showing 2000 as first and 1991 as last, using minimalist Complexity on Front-end i.e O(n). Applying orderBy is not helping me. I am not sure if i need a custom filter for this. Any leads would be appreciated as I dont want to change the JSON structure. It should be the same.

cheers.

Comment: You can't sort an object properties based on keys

Comment: Convert the object to an array of objects then sort it

Comment: what if i have to? absolutely no solution there?

Comment: there are workaround as I suggested above

Comment: You may need to rephrase the obj itself to have a benefit of orderBy:'property', you may need to format it, so the year will be a property and you can use orderBy:'property'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the objects keys and then use the keys to get the value from the object.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="key in keys">
    {{obj[key]}}
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.obj = {
  '1991': [{
    'year': 1991,
    'month': 'Jan'
  }, {
    'year': 1991,
    'month': 'Feb'
  }],
  '1992': [{
    'year': 1992,
    'month': 'March'
  }, {
    'year': 1992,
    'month': 'Dec'
  }],
  '2000': [{
    'year': 2000,
    'month': 'Jan'
  }]
};

// get object keys and sort them.
$scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.obj).reverse();
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/n841Lqr5/)**

Comment: How to make it simpler? Without second obj?